# size_t confusion in functions like snprintf

Tags: c, printf, sizeof, size-t

In functions like `snprintf`, `strlcat`, and `strlcpy` where their manpage mentions `size_t size` in the arguments of said functions, what exactly is `size`, or what's the best way to get `size`?

#### Taken from `strlcpy(3)`, `strcat(3)`, and `printf(3)` (with comments added)

```
size_t
strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size);
//                                         ^^^^

char *
strncat(char *str, const char *src, size_t n);
//                                         ^

int
snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
//                         ^^^^
```

My understanding was that `size` could (or in the case of `strncat`, should?) be obtained like so:

```
sizeof dst - strlen(dst) - 1 
// sizeof dst buffer, minus the offset of '\0', minus 1 for the null-terminator
```

But I recall reading somewhere on SO that to get the `size` of a variable that you did something like:

```
sizeof <VAR> / <SOMETHING ELSE?>
// sorry, I don't remember the rest of this method
```

Is there a difference between the two forms, are they equivalent and/or interchangeable, or are they only valid in certain circumstances?

**EDIT**:
I think I understand it a little bit better now.  `sizeof` returns the size in bytes of whatever you pass to it, but in same cases you need to take in account the size of the destination buffer *in addition* to the size of the source buffer, as in the case of `strncat`.

Comment: the size_t usually (but not always) can be treated as an unsigned int.  it is used for portability.  sizeof is a compile time operator that returns the number of bytes in some object.  your example: sizeof <VAR> / <SOMETHING ELSE?> is often used to get the number of entries in a table, by coding: sizeof (table) / sizeof (single entry in table)

Comment: @user3629249, thought it was specified to be of type unsigned integer.

Comment: strlen(dst) (for a nul terminated string) gets the offset to the nul byte at the end of the string.  However, since offsets start with 0, it is (also) the number of bytes in the string.

Comment: given this line: 'sizeof dst - strlen(dst) - 1'  this actually gives the number of bytes in dst that are NOT being occupied  by (the string + the nul terminator byte)  I.E. if dst is 30 bytes and strlen returns 20 bytes then the count of unused bytes is: 30 - 20 -1 = 9 unused bytes

Comment: `size_t` is an `unsigned` type able to store the size of the largest possible object. Hopefully, it's at least `unsigned int` (no guarantee, advisable due to default integer promotions), though it can be `unsigned long long` equally well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For strlcpy, you give it the size of the buffer. If the buffer has size 100, strlcpy can copy up to 99 chars plus a zero byte.

For strlcat, you give it the size of the buffer. strlcat figures out how many bytes are already there.

The whole point of strlcpy, strlcat, snprintf is that you give it the size of the buffer and the function figures out the rest, instead of you calculating how many bytes are available. That's because people calculating sizes make mistakes, so calling strlcpy and calculating how many bytes are available yourself defeats the purpose.